# Can Regex do conditional values?

Tags: java, regex, unit-testing

I have a String being generated by concatenating a set of String with a comma delimeter. Now I want to write a unit test covering this code, I want to check that all Strings in the set made it into the concatenated String. The problem is that sets are not ordered, so I can't know for sure what the concatenated String will be. And I can't change the Set to an ordered Set or a List as I don't own that bit of code.

As an example, if my set was {"VAL1", "VAL2"}, my test currently looks like this:

```
assertTrue("VAL1,VAL2".equals(concString) || "VAL2,VAL1".equals(concString));
```

This is fine, but if my set had 5, or even 10 values, this will become impractical. So I considered changing it to:

```
assertTrue("VAL[1-2],VAL[1-2]".matches(concString));
```

However this could also match the incorrect case "VAL1,VAL1". Is there a way in regex to say "use this set of values, but don't match a value that was matched already"?

Comment: How about splitting the string again and then perform the comparison with a set of predefined values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general no, but in this case, yes.

```
Pattern.compile("^VAL([12]),VAL(?!\\1\\b)([12])$")
```

This matches

1. `VAL`
2. followed by *[12]* with the matching text stored in group 1
3. followed by `,VAL`
4. followed by text that is not the same as group 1 followed by a word-break
5. followed by *[12]* with the matching text stored in group 2

The "is not" is handled by the negative lookahead operator `(?!...)` and `\1` is a back-reference to the content stored in group 1.

---

This is a little complicated for a unit test.

Unit test code should be as simple as possible so that you're not confused about what you're testing.

If the number of variants is small,

```
ImmutableSet.of("VAL1,VAL2", "VAL2,VAL1").contains(...)
```

is simpler and readable.

If the number of variants is not that small, then splitting, sorting, and joining can help you get a canonical value to test against.

Comment: Using set.of(...).contains is definitely more readable than lots of " || " operators